# An error occurred while installing unf_ext (0.0.7.2), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

I was trying to install diaspora into localhost. I removed the `Gemfile.lock` file and tried `bundle install` and am seeing this.

These are the things I already tried

- `ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install unf_ext`
- `xcode-select --install`
- `sudo xcodebuild -license`

  ```
  Krishnas-MacBook-Air:diaspora KrishnaTeja$ bundle install
  Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/....
  Fetching version metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
  Fetching dependency metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
  Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
  Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
  Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
  Resolving dependencies..............................
  Using rake 11.3.0
  Using CFPropertyList 2.3.4
  Using i18n 0.7.0
  Using json 1.8.3
  Using minitest 5.10.1
  Using thread_safe 0.3.5
  Using builder 3.2.2
  Using erubis 2.7.0
  Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
  Using rack 1.6.5
  Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
  Using arel 6.0.3
  Using addressable 2.4.0
  Using excon 0.54.0
  Using formatador 0.2.5
  Using multi_json 1.12.1
  Using ipaddress 0.8.3
  Using xml-simple 1.1.5
  Using inflecto 0.0.2
  Using trollop 2.1.2
  Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system Rubygems.
  You can cancel this installation and run:

    bundle install --path vendor/bundle



  to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your  password


  and install the bundled gems to Rubygems using sudo.
  Password: 
  Installing unf_ext 0.0.7.2 with native extensions
  Using ast 2.3.0
  Using attr_required 1.0.1
  Using execjs 2.7.0
  Using coffee-script-source 1.11.1
  Using eco-source 1.1.0.rc.1
  Using ejs 1.1.1
  Using thor 0.19.4
  Installing bcrypt 3.1.11 with native extensions
  Using bindata 2.3.4
  Using sass 3.4.22
  Using bootstrap-switch-rails 3.3.3
  Using buftok 0.2.0
  Using bundler 1.13.6
  Installing byebug 9.0.6 with native extensions
  Using mimemagic 0.3.2
  Installing hitimes 1.2.4 with native extensions
  Installing nio4r 1.2.1 with native extensions
  Using chunky_png 1.3.8
  Using cliver 0.3.2
  Using coderay 1.1.1
  Using rb-fsevent 0.9.7
  Using ffi 1.9.14
  Using hike 1.2.3
  Using tilt 1.4.1
  Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
  Using configurate 0.3.1
  Using connection_pool 2.2.1
  Using docile 1.1.5
  Using simplecov-html 0.10.0
  Using tins 1.13.0
  Using safe_yaml 1.0.4
  Using gherkin 4.0.0
  Using cucumber-wire 0.0.1
  Using diff-lcs 1.2.5
  Using multi_test 0.1.2
  Using rspec-support 3.5.0
  Using database_cleaner 1.5.3
  Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
  Using diaspora-prosody-config 0.0.7
  Using multipart-post 2.0.0
  Using valid 1.2.0
  Using equalizer 0.0.10
  Installing sigar 0.7.3 with native extensions
  Using state_machine 1.2.0
  Using ruby-progressbar 1.8.1
  Using get_process_mem 0.2.1
  Using multi_xml 0.5.5
  Using unicode-display_width 1.1.1
  Using request_store 1.3.1
  Using ruby_dep 1.5.0
  Using lumberjack 1.0.10
  Using nenv 0.3.0
  Using shellany 0.0.1
  Using method_source 0.8.2
  Using slop 3.6.0
  Using guard-compat 1.2.1
  Using powerpack 0.1.1
  Using rainbow 2.1.0
  Using sysexits 1.2.0
  Using temple 0.7.7
  Using hashdiff 0.3.1
  Using hashie 3.4.6
  Using http-form_data 1.0.1
  Installing http_parser.rb 0.6.0 with native extensions
  Using http_accept_language 2.0.5
  Using httpclient 2.8.2.4
  Using jasmine-core 2.5.2
  Using phantomjs 2.1.1.0
  Using jasmine-jquery-rails 2.0.3
  Using securecompare 1.0.0
  Using url_safe_base64 0.2.2
  Using jwt 1.5.6
  Installing kgio 2.10.0 with native extensions
  Using leaflet-rails 0.7.7
  Using little-plugger 1.1.4
  Using systemu 2.6.5
  Using markerb 1.1.0
  Using mini_magick 4.5.1
  Using naught 1.1.0
  Using nested_form 0.3.2
  Using oauth 0.5.1
  Using websocket-extensions 0.1.2
  Installing rugged 0.24.0 with native extensions
  Using rack-cors 0.4.0
  Using rack-piwik 0.3.0
  Using rack-rewrite 1.5.1
  Using rails-assets-autosize 3.0.17
  Using rails-assets-blueimp-gallery 2.21.3
  Using rails-assets-jquery 2.2.4
  Using rails-assets-emojione 2.0.1
  Using rails-assets-favico.js 0.3.10
  Using rails-assets-jquery-fullscreen-plugin 0.5.0
  Using rails-assets-jquery.slimscroll 1.3.8
  Using rails-assets-highlightjs 9.7.0
  Using rails-assets-jasmine 2.5.2
  Using rails-assets-markdown-it 8.0.0
  Using rails-assets-markdown-it--markdown-it-for-inline 0.1.1
  Using rails-assets-markdown-it-diaspora-mention 1.0.0
  Using rails-assets-markdown-it-hashtag 0.4.0
  Using rails-assets-markdown-it-sanitizer 0.4.3
  Using rails-assets-markdown-it-sub 1.0.0
  Using rails-assets-markdown-it-sup 1.0.0
  Using rails-assets-perfect-scrollbar 0.6.12
  Using remotipart 1.3.1
  Installing raindrops 0.17.0 with native extensions
  Installing redcarpet 3.3.4 with native extensions
  Using redis 3.3.2
  Using ruby-oembed 0.10.1
  Using rubyzip 1.2.0
  Using useragent 0.16.8
  Using simple_oauth 0.3.1
  Using yard 0.9.5
  Using timecop 0.8.1
  Using turbo_dev_assets 0.0.2
  Using will_paginate 3.1.5
  Using fission 0.5.0
  Using i18n-inflector 2.6.7
  Using tzinfo 1.2.2
  Using memoizable 0.4.2
  Installing nokogiri 1.6.8.1 with native extensions
  Using rack-test 0.6.3
  Using warden 1.2.6
  Using rack-mobile-detect 0.4.0
  Using rack-protection 1.5.3
  Using rack-ssl 1.4.1
  Using mime-types 3.1
  Using json-schema 2.7.0
  Using fog-core 1.43.0
  Using jsonpath 0.5.8
  Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

  current directory:       /private/var/folders/nb/j6bftgxj0bd7zq5g98hn3xnc0000gn/T/bundler20161204-90063-19uje57unf_ext-0.0.7.2/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.2/ext/unf_ext
  /Users/KrishnaTeja/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/ruby -r      ./siteconf20161204-90063-15sm4gh.rb extconf.rb
  checking for main() in -lstdc++... *** extconf.rb failed ***
  Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of  necessary
  libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
  need configuration options.

  Provided configuration options:
  --with-opt-dir
  --without-opt-dir
  --with-opt-include
  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
  --with-opt-lib
  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
  --with-make-prog
  --without-make-prog
  --srcdir=.
  --curdir
  --ruby=/Users/KrishnaTeja/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
  --with-static-libstdc++
  --without-static-libstdc++
  --with-stdc++lib
  --without-stdc++lib



  /Users /KrishnaTeja/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in    `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file.   (RuntimeError)
      You have to install development tools first.
      from 
      /Users /KrishnaTeja/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
      from 

      /Users /KrishnaTeja/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
      from
      /Users /KrishnaTeja/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:765:in `try_func'
  from /Users/KrishnaTeja/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:997:in `block in have_library'
  from /Users/KrishnaTeja/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:942:in `block in checking_for'
  from /Users/KrishnaTeja/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
  from /Users/KrishnaTeja/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
  from /Users/KrishnaTeja/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
  from /Users/KrishnaTeja/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
  from /Users/KrishnaTeja/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
  from /Users/KrishnaTeja/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
  from /Users/KrishnaTeja/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:992:in `have_library'
  from extconf.rb:6:in `<main>'

  To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/folders/nb/j6bftgxj0bd7zq5g98hn3xnc0000gn/T/bundler20161204-90063-19uje57unf_ext-0.0.7.2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0-static/unf_ext-0.0.7.2/mkmf.log

  extconf failed, exit code 1

  Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/nb/j6bftgxj0bd7zq5g98hn3xnc0000gn/T/bundler20161204-90063-19uje57unf_ext-0.0.7.2/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.2 for inspection.
  Results logged to /var/folders/nb/j6bftgxj0bd7zq5g98hn3xnc0000gn/T/bundler20161204-90063-19uje57unf_ext-0.0.7.2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0-static/unf_ext-0.0.7.2/gem_make.out

  An error occurred while installing unf_ext (0.0.7.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
  Make sure that `gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.7.2'` succeeds before bundling.
  ```

I looked at others similar questions but nothing helped. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For those who get this `An error occurred while installing unf_ext` problem while installing fastlane this often happens if you have too old ruby version. Default ruby in macOS has version 2.6.x and you need at least 2.7.x to make it work without problems. In such case I recommend installing ruby version manager (https://rvm.io/) and adding `ruby "2.7.6"` line to your Gemfile. Then ruby version manager will enforce that you use this version of ruby when installing gems and the problem should go away.

Comment: It solved issue in my case. I've tried many solutions without success and finally found this answer. Hard to believe it was that simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed Xcode, deleted gemlock file, updated bundled and finally bundle install....everything went smooth and the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

`sudo apt-get install ruby-dev` and continue `bundle install`

Answer (score -3):

You can try this :

```
 sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

Comment: Am using a mac and this is what I could see 

`Krishnas-MacBook-Air:diaspora KrishnaTeja$ brew install libgmp-dev1
`Error: No available formula with the name "libgmp-dev" `
`==> Searching for similarly named formulae...`
`Error: No similarly named formulae found.`
`==> Searching taps...`
`Error: No formulae found in taps.`

Comment: Please refer above link and check it again.

Comment: `Krishnas-MacBook-Air:diaspora KrishnaTeja$ brew install gmp
Error: Your Xcode (6.4) is too outdated.
Please update to Xcode 8.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.`

this is what I see when I tried followed the link you provided. Am I missing anything.

Comment: 1. Open up App Store

 ![enter image description here][1]

 2. Look in the top right for the updates section

 ![enter image description here][2]

 3. Find Xcode & click Update
 ![enter image description here][3]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BVp6D.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Skf8z.png
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FovPK.png

Comment: Please follow above three steps

Comment: softwareupdate --list see the list of outdated software.

softwareupdate --install --allupdate all outdated software.

softwareupdate --install <product name> update the software you named.

Comment: `Krishnas-MacBook-Air:diaspora KrishnaTeja$ softwareupdate --list
Software Update Tool
Copyright 2002-2015 Apple Inc.

Finding available software
No new software available.`


Also I tried doing the three steps you mentioned and I see the install button for Xcode in AppStore and am installing it. Looks like its a 8 gb app.

Comment: I re-installed Xcode, deleted gemlock file, updated bundler and finally did bundle install....everything went smooth and the app started.