# bundle install gem could not find unf_ext

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle

A test project I'm trying to get working has a dependency on the `unf_ext` 0.0.7.4 gem being installed and I'm having trouble with it.

If I run `bundle install` I get:

```
<some packages>
Using unf_ext 0.0.7.4
<some package>

Bundle complete! 6 Gemfile dependencies, 27 gems now installed.
```

but if I then do `bundle info unf_ext` I get:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find unf_ext-0.0.7.4 in any of the sources
```

If I try `gem install unf_ext` I get

> could not create makefile

and when I open the `mkmf.log` file it says:

```
checked program was:

/* begin */

1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <ruby.h>
4: int main(int argc, char **argv)
5: {
6:   return 0;
7: }
/* end */
```

If I run `sudo gem install unf_ext` I get:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed unf_ext-0.0.7.4
Parsing documentation for unf_ext-0.0.7.4
Done installing documentation for unf_ext after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

but then `gem list` doesn't contain `unt_ext`.

Anyone know why it's not installing despite seemingly suggesting that it is?

Comment: I had to blow out my .bundle directory. Looks like it used to not be installed with "native extensions" and now it IS installed with "native extensions." Curse you, native extensions! Rargh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly same errors and only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72056295/286361) solution helped me.

So in my case the cause was too old ruby version (< 2.7). All work as expected after updating ruby.
But ensure that new ruby version is actually used as system one. I've used rbenv to manage versions.